# convert system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource to microsoft.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource

Tags: windows-runtime, winui-3

I thought this would be easy (and built-in) but alas not. Does anyone know of a simply way to convert this ?

I'm getting the thumbnail of files/folders and using this code (from WPF, now using WinUI 3 for desktop). I can't use the WinRT Windows.Storage.FileProperties.StorageItemThumbnail because of the threading model it uses with the RunTimeBroker.

```
using var shellFolder = ShellFileSystemFolder.FromFolderPath(this.Path);
shellFolder.Thumbnail.CurrentSize = new Size(requestedSize, requestedSize);
result = shellFolder.Thumbnail.BitmapSource;
result.Freeze();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a C# code that convert from [WPF's BitmapSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource) to [WinUI3 BitmapSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.imaging.softwarebitmapsource), using bitmap's pixels copy from one to the other.

```
public static async Task<Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.SoftwareBitmapSource> GetWinUI3BitmapSourceFromWpfBitmapSource(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource bitmapSource)
{
    if (bitmapSource == null)
        return null;

    // get pixels as an array of bytes
    var stride = bitmapSource.PixelWidth * bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
    var bytes = new byte[stride * bitmapSource.PixelHeight];
    bitmapSource.CopyPixels(bytes, stride, 0);

    // get WinRT SoftwareBitmap
    var softwareBitmap = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap(
        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        bitmapSource.PixelWidth,
        bitmapSource.PixelHeight,
        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
    softwareBitmap.CopyFromBuffer(bytes.AsBuffer());

    // build WinUI3 SoftwareBitmapSource
    var source = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.SoftwareBitmapSource();
    await source.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap);
    return source;
}
```

Note that depending on how you got the "bitmap" (whatever format that is, GDI, WPF, etc), there may be smarter ways as this is allocating usually a **4 * width * height** byte array for the whole bitmap.

Also, it would probably be good to review your threading issues, using WinRT all along is probably better.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try the code tomorrow.
Regarding the threading issues, it’s outside of my control. WinRT’s storage system goes through the runtime broker, an external security barrier. That system is single threaded per exe; so, I can send 10 threads at the file system, and the runtime broker will process them one at a time. A great security system by microsoft, but a killer performance wise.